# Missing operator or semicolon

Tags: delphi-7

у меня есть dbgrid, в нем два столбца хочу скопировать при "Ctl+C" оба столбца

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сделал так но есть ошибка перед равно (=)

```
procedure TForm24.mniN2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin 
 Clipboard.AsText:=qry2.FieldValues['name_subagent']'+#39+'='+#39+'Clipboard.AsText:=qry3.FieldValues['result'];
end;
```

> [Error] Missing operator or semicolon

сделал таким образом но есть ошибка

```
Clipboard.AsText:=qry2.FieldValues['name_subagent']+'='+qry2.FieldValues['result'];
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно.

Answer (score 0):

Это странная строчка (видимо, порождение копипаста)

```
 Clipboard.AsText:=qry2.FieldValues['name_subagent']'+#39+'='+#39+'Clipboard.AsText:=qry3.FieldValues['result'];
```

По идее должно быть как-то так:

```
Clipboard.AsText := qry2.FieldValues['name_subagent'];
Clipboard.AsText := Clipboard.AsText + '#39'; //Я так понял #39 это разделитель в строке
Clipboard.AsText := Clipboard.AsText + qry3.FieldValues['result'];
```

или, короче:

```
Clipboard.AsText := qry2.FieldValues['name_subagent'] +'#39'+ qry3.FieldValues['result'];
```

**Дополнение** Нашел в Интернете:

> EVariantTypeCastError is raised when a variant operation fails because a value could not be cast to the destination variant type.

В вашем случае, похоже, не проходит конвертация Currency в строку, то есть надо пробежать по возвращаемому Variant из `qry3.FieldValues['result']` и конвернуть значения вручную, в строку (в начале в список строк, который потом уже в целую строку, а потому уже складывать с первым столбцом, который, похоже, преобразовался в строку автоматически).